# Changing current username and password for when Eclipse connects to svn

Tags: java, eclipse, tortoisesvn

I want to change the current username and password through which I am connected to SVN. Because when I commit it show another user through which I am currently connected to SVN.

Comment: Which eclipse svn plugin are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You should clear your svn authentication data at first. When you connect to SVN next time, you'll be asked to input your user info as your wish.

You will find the clear button in TortoiseSVN's settings >> Saved Data.